# React.js Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid:

Tags: reactjs

I get this error in a browser.

> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Tabbox_order`.

Here is my 'Tabbox_orber.js' file

```
import React from "react";

import Walker from './Walker';
import Order from './Order';

require('../css/Tabbox-order.scss');

const Tabbox_order = (props) => {
  const Order = props.orders.map((order, index) => {
    return <Order order={order} key={index} />
  });

  return(
    <div id='tabbox-order'>
      <div id='tabbox-bar'>
        <p>Username</p>
        <p>Service Details</p>
        <span>Address</span>
      </div>
      <div id='Cutting' ></div>
      {Order}
    </div>
  )

}


export default Tabbox_order
```

And Here is my 'Order.js' file.

```
import React from "react";

require('../css/Order.scss');

const Order = ({order}) => {

  return(

    <div id='order-info'>
      <div className='infor'>
        <img src='../../img/logo.png'></img>

        <div>{order.pet.name}</div>

        <div>8 mins ago</div>
      </div>
      <div className='infor'>
        <img src='../../img/logo.png'></img>

        <div>Zichen Wang</div>

        <div>8 mins ago</div>
      </div>
      <div className='infor'>
        <img src='../../img/logo.png'></img>

        <div>Zichen Wang</div>
        <div>8 mins ago</div>
      </div>

    </div>


  )
}

export default Order
```

The `props.orders` in `Tabbox.js` is an array of objects I passed from `Layout.js`.

So I used the arrow function to define this component, I don't know what does this error means. Could someone help me? Really appreciated that!

I added `console.log` inside the `props.orders.map` function and it works. It prints twice because of the `props.order` is an array has two object. Now the problem is the `Order.js` don't show up.

Comment: Any reason you don't have a render function anywhere?

Comment: I have the render function in Layout.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the name clash between the component's name `Order` that you import and the `const Order` that you define and subsequently use in the render method. Try changing the latter to something else

Comment: have you tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` ?

Comment: `console.log` the result of `props.orders.map` function, I think it's undefined, hence the error

Comment: I added the `console.log `into that function. It don' work. But I used that function before it worked well. And I just want to use that `map` show all the orders.

Comment: Sorry!The `console.log` inside the `props.orders.map` works. It prints twice because of the `props.order` is an array has two object. Now the problem is the `Order.js` don't show up.

Comment: The code works for me when I change `const Order = props.orders.map...` to `const orders= props.orders.map...` and then also in the render function `{Order}` to `{orders}` with this mock data: `[{pet:{name:'xxx'}},{pet:{name:'yyyy'}}]`